# Google Analytics events stopped tracking yesterday

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to determine why our event tracking in Google Analytics has virtually stopped working for us.

We are on Shopify, but we have a few other third party apps that send events to our GA acct.

All of the events are recording extremely low numbers in GA.

We have other ways to count most of the events we track in GA, and those numbers do not show a decrease. So the events are happening... just not being reflected in GA.

Any one else seeing this issue?